# How to send data to wifi printer

Tags: android, printing, wifi, zebra-printers

I need to print string using my application via wifi printer. My application will be work only in my wifi structure so even printer IP can by static. How to send data to printer?

Comment: What is the problem? Why would it be different from sending a Strimg to your own socket server if you had one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zebra has an sdk for Android. With that you can discover and connect to printers.